# depend on a dom hover or an array of divs, positions and dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is it good to depend on the dom (CSS)hover, for detecting when i'm on another div, or figure that from the already stored array of all the div.s positions and dimensions on the page, 
keep in mind that the said array, **updates every time** an element changes either position/dimension
i want the process to be effecient, a part of me want to depend on that array for detecting when i'm over another div. but i'm afraid that, that will be an extra processing.
can anybody please help me ?? (***thanks in advance***)

Comment: If you CAN do something in css, I'd say go for the css way since that should give better performance. Not quite sure I understand what you mean though.

Comment: Yes, basing it on an array containing every element does make processing much more intense. For nearly everything using CSS `:hover` or javascript's `onhover` performs much better. There really is no need for using an array of *every* element because javascript & CSS makes it easy to do functions based on type/classes/ids to make it more specific and less processing intensive

Comment: ok, thanks i'll use that for now, but let me explain first to be sure that we are in the same page, i'm developing a wire framing application, one of the requirements  is to draw inside another already existing div. which you would have created earlier, or just dragging a div, into another, the question was should i detect what div i'm over with something like jQuery On("Hover") method of do the array calculations to deduce that.

Comment: For dragging use jQuery's `draggable` and `droppable` since you're already using jQuery. For the drawing I'd use something like canvas most likely

Comment: @Zeaklous, i'm now using jQuery `draggable` to handle element's dragging, at first i was using droppable but then when i drag an element around and later try to drag another element inside it resulted in a wired detection for the droppables locations, of course i'm using the `refreshPositions` option, keep in mind that jQuery droppable relay on an array of stored dimensions and positions for detecting dropzones, thus my question :)

Comment: Phrase your question better next time, that would have been very helpful information. Provide your situation and why you are asking the question

Comment: ok, i'll thanks, but really the question was about whether to use the Hover or the array calculation, but since you mentioned the jQuery's `draggable` and `droppable` , i thought i'd tell you what i've tried to se if that's going to change your answer, but really sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, **relying on the DOM would be the more advantageous of the two**. Like, arbitter said, relying on CSS will probably have a very slight performance advantage, but really this type of process wouldn't slow down your program all that much, if any.